# Create a list out of the keys in a dictionary taking into account their corresponding value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, counter

For example if I have this dictionary: {1:2,2:3}, I would like to obtain this list:
[1,1,2,2,2]

Comment: Ok. What have you tried?

Comment: You don't mean 'value', you mean 'count' or 'multiplicity'. Hence your dictionary is not really a dictionary, rather a Counter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list_of_values = list()
for key, val in d.items():
    list_of_values.extend([key] * val)
print(list_of_values)
```

This prints:

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: Just a quick question. Why did you write in the third line of code ([key]*val) and why doesn´t it work if I write (list(key)*val)?

Comment: In order to create a list using a type constructor, you can either do `list()` or `list([iterable])`. 'key' in your case, is an integer, and that produces an error. You can look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list for a detailed explanation as well.

Answer (score 3):

You could e.g. use a nested list comprehension with a `range` over the corresponding value:

```
>>> d = {1: 2, 2: 3}
>>> [k for k in d for _ in range(d[k])]
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create a [`Counter` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and then use the `.elements()` method to get an iterable which you can convert to a list:

```
from collections import Counter
list(Counter({1:2,2:3}).elements())
#[1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

This allows you to also use other methods which may be of interest to you. For instance `.most_common` is often handy.

Comment: Nice, did not even know this function.

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import chain
print(list(chain.from_iterable([[k] * v for k, v in {1:2,2:3}.items()])))
```

This outputs:

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: Is all the inner list creation required?

Comment: If you use this method then yes it's required. But there are plenty of other methods that do not need the inner list creation as demonstrated in the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

Using `chain`, `repeat` and `starmap` from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat, starmap

d = {1:2,2:3}
res = chain.from_iterable(starmap(repeat, d.items()))

print(list(res))

[1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```